# Styling Gtk with css on windows

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3

I have a Gtk app I'm releasing for windows and I'm trying to do a little bit of syle via css. I put the following css (for tesing) in `MYAPP\etc\gtk-3.0\gtk.css` but nothing changes.

```
*
{
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #00FF00;
}

GtkMenuItem
{
    color: #FF0000;
    margin: 5px;
}

GtkTextView
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Is the file in the wrong location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the location is wrong.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html#GtkCssProvider.description) you should save it under `datadir/share/themes/theme-name/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` that, on Windows and supposing you are using the standard *Adwaita* theme, should be `YOURAPP\share\themes\Adwaita\gtk-3.0\gtk.css`.